# Changing the VIM/GVIM message window behavior

Tags: vim

When I type :!ls, for example, and see the result, it shifts up the current window to make space for it.

I've been annoyed by how the whole content moves up and down. I'm wondering if there's a way to fix that in either vim or gvim 7.3 - like in Emacs.

So for example, if I have lines 1~30, and the message area takes up 5 lines, I want my code window to show lines 1~25 instead of 6~30. That's what Emacs does, I think.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible in vim. However, there are ways to get around it. You can use `screen` or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and use that to create a lower window to execute commands in. You can also take a look into [conque](https://github.com/rson/vim-conque), which simulates a terminal within vim.